# Why is Materialize CSS forms not enclosed in boxes?

Tags: css, html, material-design, materialize, bootstrap-4

How do create a form like in the one in Bootstrap 4 http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/ in Materialize CSS.  The following only shows an underline for the input field and not a containing box?

```
    <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the Materialize CSS styles by using " !important ".
I have made a CodePen to demonstrate the same using the markup given. (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yzVXWN)
Also note that the I have included the Materialize CSS stylesheet in the CodePen to test this.

You can copy and paste the CSS in between the opening and closing `<style>` tags 
inside the head like this:

```
<style>
#first_name{
  display: block!important;
  width: auto !important;
  padding: .5rem!important;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
  transition: all 1s;
  border-radius: .25rem!important;
  box-shadow: none;
}

#first_name:focus{
  border-color: blue!important;
}
label{
  color:#9e9e9e!important;
}
</style>
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: this is a big help.